# NSSavePanel: Squelching the "confirm replace?" dialog

Tags: cocoa, macos, nssavepanel

In the Nav Services world one could specify `kNavDontConfirmReplacement` as an option to create a `NavDialogRef` that would not ask the user to confirm the replacement of a file when saving with a file name that already exists. How do I specify an equivalent behavior with the Cocoa `NSSavePanel`?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to replace it with my own confirm-overwrite dialog.

Comment: Could hijack the undocumented API `- (BOOL)_overwriteExistingFileCheck:(id)arg1;` and/or `- (BOOL)_shouldAlertForFileOverwrite:(id)arg1;` and return `NO`. Won't work for a sandboxed application, though.

Comment: @Eljay you are a champion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it can be done:

1. Add a delegate to handle NSSavePanel callbacks
2. Override `- (NSString*)panel:(id)sender userEnteredFilename:(NSString*)filename confirmed:(BOOL)okFlag` in your delegate
3. In the delegate:

   1. If `okFlag` is `false`, return `filename`
   2. Otherwise, retain `filename` as an `NSString*` in your delegate
   3. Return some unique string that is highly unlikely to be the name of an actual file
4. When `NSSavePanel` returns to your code, pull the value of filename from your delegate method, and discard whatever filename `NSSavePanel` told you (which should be your unique string).

Since `userEnteredFilename:` is called by the OS before the confirm-replace check is made it gives you a chance to get what the user specified without letting the OS in on the secret. The unique string will assure that the confirm-replace dialog is not popped accidentally.

Gross but efficacious.

Comment: Beware that filename may contain slashes. Save panel’s default behavior seems to be to convert them to colons.

Comment: This seems to go contrarty to the human interface guidelines not to break the users expectation.  There must be a way to do this the correct ( ie less gross ) way. 
Very slick idea btw

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to do this with NSSavePanel.  In theory you could extend NSSavePanel with a category and override certain private methods.  I took a quick look though and there is nothing simple about it.

Comment: Some discussion of doing that using overrides here:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DisableAlertBoxInNSSavePanel

Answer (score 0):

Your customers is going to expect the exact confirmation alert when faced with a NSSavePanel, so don't customize it.

I'm not sure what kind of customized confirm-overwrite dialog you are planning, but might I suggest you use a NSOpenPanel instead, and customize this dialog box with a "Create New File" button? (I believe you can do this via setAccessoryView API.)

For example, if you are asking your customer to choose a file to append new data to, the NSOpenPanel will work quite well; and if the customer want to save the new data to a new file (instead of appending to an existing file), the "Create New File" button is just an additional click.